# How force is transferred from one body to another

Tags: forces, momentum, interactions

If there are 3 coins , namely 1 , 2 and 3 as in figure.

When coin $1$ strike coin $2$ ,the coin $2$ passes the force to coin $3$ and the coin $3$ moves away.

[image: Case 1]

Case :1
 How does this happen?
 What exactly happens there and passes the force on coin $1$ to coin $3$?
 How does the force cause movement?
 I mean that when we push any object, why does it moves?

Case 2:

What will happen if there are just 2 coins and coin $1$ strikes coin $2$ and coin $2$ moves?

How and why does coin 2 move in this case?

Please don't say that there is no opposite force or net force is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simplified picture:

Let's say you have a slow motion camera, and you can see in detail what happens in the fractions of second it takes for this process to occur. What you would see is that when 1 and 2 start touching they start deforming a bit.

This deformation is kinetic energy of 1 transforming into potential energy of 1 and 2... and just a bit later into potential energy of three as well, since 2 is compressing and exerting compression on 3 as well. Well instants later all this compression was transformed into the force that put 3 into motion.

Now why did 2 stay in its position? Well we are assuming that at least 1 and three have equal masses, if this was not the case, then the result would be different. We are also assuming the knock was completely elastic. This means that all energy stayed kinetic, no coin remained with internal energy, that is none stayed deformed, not even vibrating.

Still, how to explain that 2 stayed? Well since 1 and 3 are identical, the deformation on 1 when hitting two is instantaneously transmitted to 3 through 2. This happens only when 2 is very small or very strongly made (so that compression on one side travels so fast that no portion of 2 can move faster with respect to the other, this is close to an [ideal solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body)).

If this were not true, then 2 would deform and the transmission of movement to 3 would take longer time, and 2 would move some distance before completely giving its internal energy to kinetic energy of 3.

So basically, the system behaves much like if 1 hitted 3 directly, and 2 remains a spectator.

Comment: Why there is deformation.

Comment: There is deformation because only ideal bodies can be really rigid. However, real bodies can be very rigid, like diamond. And if we realize that the important thing is how fast deformations travel through the body, most of solids are kind of rigid for us, since we are not able to distinguish the deformations, on the timescales they occur.

Comment: I mean that if any force is applied on a body how does the body moves.This could  be A foolish question but i am really stuck on it.

Comment: This is hard to explain without a framework. In the newtonian picture, a force an interaction between bodies, which can always be equated to the rate of velocity change of a body. Hence is in the definition of force, so is hard to explain how it produces what is defined to produce ab initio. As a footnote, I don't think is a foolish question, but maybe you should think deep on what exactly has you stuck, and maybe formulate a more elaborate version of your thinking, so it could be answered better.

Comment: As 1 hits 2, the atoms at the surface of 2 feel the electrostatic repulsion due to the atoms at the surface of 1. The atoms at the surface of 2 are accelerated, and move (very slightly!) toward the second layer.  This transmits momentum to the second layer.  The second layer transmits to the third, etc.  Eventually all the atoms in the coin are in motion.  Much of that motion is random (thermal energy), but conservation of momentum tells us that there is a preponderance of momentum in the direction of the collision force.  The entire coin moves (and is a little warmer).

Comment: I wrote my question here.http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228433/how-do-momentum-get-transferred

Answer (score 0):

A different example from your coins, but the same idea, is Newton's cradle.

[image]

Pull one ball away, it hits the first ball in the line and comes to nearly a complete halt. The ball on the opposite side, like your coins,  gets most of the initial velocity and almost instantly swings in an arc nearly, but not quite as high as the height of ball you dropped at the start.

This example demonstrates that the final ball receives most of the energy and momentum that was in the first ball. A wave of compression moves through the intermediate balls.

> I mean that if any force is applied on a body how does the body moves.This could be a foolish question but i am really stuck on it.

As to how a force makes a body move, the second body has no choice but to move, if can move freely, because of the [law of conservation of energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy). Possibly, rather than thinking about how the body moves, ask yourself, what would happen if bodies did **not** move when a force is applied to them?

Comment: I think a very important point in this answer is the wave of compression.  It makes clear the fact that the process is not instantaneous.  But it is often *very fast*.

Comment: I wrote my full question here could you take a look.http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228433/how-do-momentum-get-transferred