# Elastic collision

Tags: energy, collision

In an elastic collision, 2 processes can be said to take place as mentioned here in the accepted answer: [Why does a billiard ball stop when it hits another billiard ball head on?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429874/why-does-a-billiard-ball-stop-when-it-hits-another-billiard-ball-head-on?r=SearchResults)

First by the interacting force and then when the deformation is undone.

But why would the the latter process ('expanding back to original shape') cause changes in the energy/velocity of the same whole body ? Wouldn't it only cause changes in the local area where the deformation had taken place ?

Comment: If there is deformation, the collision is not elastic

Comment: @anna v I  think we’re talking about elastic deformation not plastic (permanent) deformation, no?

Comment: @BobD  The title says "elastic collision", elastic deformation is a different story

Comment: @annav I think the deformation referred to in the question is transient rather than permanent.

Comment: @dmckee  that is fine , except that the title does not say that. When spins and deformations enter it is not the cms elastic scatter that only changes angles.

Comment: Well, as far as I understand, (as mentioned in the given link), elastic collision results in elastic deformation.